# Вводятся координаты четырёх точек на плоскости, определить могут ли они быть вершинами выпуклого четырёхугольника

Tags: pascal

Есть следующие идеи: если у нас есть четыре точки, то выпуклый четырехугольник может получится в том, и только в том случае, если для каждой точки справедливо условие: она не лежит внутри треугольника, образованного тремя оставшимися точками (можно легко проверить, нарисовав на бумаге четыре точки, являющиеся вершинами выпуклого и невыпуклого многоугольников). Осталось теперь это записать... для каждой точки. Может, у кого-нибудь есть идеи? Спасибо.

Comment: Для каждой пары точек (6 пар) постройте прямую. Если они - вершины выпуклого 4-угольника, то во всех случаях оставшиеся 2 вершины лежат в одной полуплоскости. Это проще проверить.

Comment: В четырёх из шести - по одну. В двух - по разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Примитив

Если у вас есть три точки (`p1 = (x1, y1), p2 = (x2, y2), p3 = (x3, y3)`) на плоскости и они расположены против часовой стрелки, то этот определитель будет больше нуля:

```
| x1 y1 1 |      > 0 - точки против часовой стрелки
| x2 y2 1 |      = 0 - точки на одной прямой
| x3 y3 1 |      < 0 - точки по часовой стрелке
```

Я буду через `ds(p1, p2, p3)` (det sign) обозначать знак определителя.

### Проверка через треугольники

Через проверку знаков определителей можно установить что четвёртая точка находится внутри треугольника из первых трёх:

```
func in_triangle(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    ds123 = ds(p1, p2, p3)
    if ds123 != ds(p1, p2, p4)
        return false
    if ds123 != ds(p1, p4, p3)
        return false
    if ds123 != ds(p4, p2, p3)
        return false
    return true
```

Теперь нашу четвёрку точек разбиваем четырьмя способами на треугольник и точку. Для каждого способа проверяем что точка не внутри треугольника:

```
func convex(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    if in_triangle(p1, p2, p3, p4)
        return false
    if in_triangle(p4, p1, p2, p3)
        return false
    if in_triangle(p3, p4, p1, p2)
        return false
    if in_triangle(p4, p1, p2, p3)
        return false
    return true
```

### Как правильно

Вы спросите почему так сложно то? А потому что сделано элементарными средствами. Есть другой способ: построить [выпуклую оболочку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) и проверить что все четыре точки в неё попали. Но это за пять минут не объяснишь.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этогo знак векторного произведения.